# Connect JBossEAP 6.4 to Maven Project

Tags: maven, jboss-eap-6, wildfly-10

This is very basic question,
I have Centos 7, I have configured JAVA_HOME and Maven:

> [nodet@localhost WildFly]$ mvn -version
>   Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
>   Maven home: /data/maven
>   Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: /data/jdk1.8.0_101/jre
>   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix

When I unzip wildfly-10.0.0.Final.zip and quickstart-10.x.zip, go to helloworld directory and execute mvn clean install wildfly:deploy, I got the application deployed successfully,

BUT

When I unzip jboss-eap-6.4.zip and run the command again I got:

Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project wildfly-helloworld: Could not execute goal deploy on /data/WildFly/quickstart-10.x/helloworld/target/wildfly-helloworld.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{

> [ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
>   [ERROR] "address" => [],
>   [ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
>   [ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed: XNIO000816: Redirect encountered establishing connection

Everything is set as default, For sure the server is up, and listening to port 9990, trying to compare both WildFly and Jboss EAP standalone.xml but they aren't exactly the same (WildFly is more evoluated compared to Jboss EAP which is more stable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WildFly and JBoss EAP 6 have different default management ports. If you want to use the same plugin for both configurations you either have to use a profile for JBoss EAP which will override the `<port>9999</port>` or when you execute the `mvn` command add a system property for the port.

```
mvn clean wildfly:deploy -Dwildfly.port=9999
```

Another thing to note is WildFly is a Java EE 7 compliant container where as JBoss EAP 6 is a Java EE 6 compliant container. Some of the quickstarts from the WildFly quickstarts might not work on JBoss EAP 6. If you're wanting to use JBoss EAP instead of WildFly have a look at [JBoss EAP 7](http://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/overview/) which is a Java EE 7 compliant container based on WildFly 10.0.0.Final.

Comment: That worked, much appreciated !
I tried to add parameters to the pom.xml in the configuration subsystem
                <hostname>192.168.1.104</hostname>
                <port>9999</port>
But it didn't worked..., not sure why...